# How database is divided over multiple disk?

Tags: mysql, database, storage, hard-drive

I am talking about a computer cluster in which there are total 4 nodes and 8 hard drives of 600GB capacity but if database size goes above 1TB then how mysql database would be divided (stored) over multiple disks?

Comment: If you are looking at that much data; you should consider looking into sharding.  Although, sharding can be quite problematic it is a solution that might help you with expanding data sizes.

Comment: 8 drives but in what configuration? If it's RAID (and if not,why not?) then that's effectively a single drive, not 8 drives.

Comment: Having seen your three questions so far on SF can I strongly suggest that you hire a designer for this work, I don't mean this in a rude way but you're clearly out of your depth and almost certain to make large and hard-to-fix design issues.

Comment: ^^Not rude at all and indeed its a good idea. Would you recommend couple of good designers?

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [MySql Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can grow beyond the capacity of a single disk using a [RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) setup. From your description it is not clear whether you are already using RAID. You claim to already have more than 1 hard drive per server - are they only configured as a mirror (RAID-1)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion actually I am likely to face this situation and currently its not on ground situation. So, please tell me how when RAID will be implemented how login node will know about the particular database record is saved on which disk?

Comment: You don't know how RAID works?  I think you've got a lot of reading to do.